# How to submit form using JQuery and CakePHP?

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a form and I would submit this form to my controller using JQuery without use JsHelper of CakePHP but I don't know how I could do this.

How could I do this ?

I'm trying this.

```
//add.ctp

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#formulario').submit(function(){
            var dados = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "UsersController.php",
                data: dados,
                success: function( data )
                {
                    alert( data );
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>


<div class="col-lg-6">
                <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array("id"=>"formulario"); ?> 

                    <div class="form-group">                         
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('nome', array( "label"=>"Nome",
                                                                     "placeholder"=>"Informe o nome",                                                                                               
                                                                     "class"=>"form-control",                                                                     
                                                                     ));?>                        

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">                                            
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('email', array("label"=>"Email",
                                                                     "placeholder"=>"Informe o email",                                                                                               
                                                                     "class"=>"form-control",                                                                     
                                                                     ));?>                        

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">                                            
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('senha', array("type"=>"password",                                                                    
                                                                     "maxlength"=>8,                                                                     
                                                                     "style"=>"width:200px;",
                                                                     "class"=>"form-control"));?>                        

                    </div>                

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Gravar</button>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->button("Limpar", array("type"=>"reset", "class"=>"btn btn-success"));?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: I don't see any glaring issues with your code. Should work. What's the problem, what's not working, do you get any errors?

Comment: @Zealander the form doesn't submit

Comment: Any errors in the browser console? Hit F12 and go to Console tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an obvious error:

```
url: "UsersController.php",
```

The name of a file is not where the form should be posted you need to use a url such as the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#formulario').submit(function(){
            var dados = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:$(this).attr('action'),
                data: dados,
                success: function( data )
                {
                    alert( data );
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Also your requested function should be allowed by auth as follows.

```
$this->Auth->allow(array('add', 'register','whatever_you_want'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your url like

```
url: "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'Users','action'=>'index'));?>",
```